# How to get a list of updated/inserted rows into a SQL Server database after multiple stored procedure have executed?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Consider Java application reading/modifying data from a SQL Server database using only stored procedures.

I am interested in knowing exactly what rows were inserted/updated after execution of some code.

Code that is executing could trigger multiple stored procedures and these procedures are working with different tables in general case.

My current solution is to debug low level Java code executed before any of stored procedures is called and inspecting parameters passed, to manually reconstruct impacts.

This seem to be ineffective and unreliable.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you can enable SQL trace on server (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1710/capture-all-statements-for-a-sql-server-session/ ) , it will be most reliable way to catch all the statements.

Answer (score 1):

To know exactly what rows were inserted/updated after execution of some code, you can implement [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql) for UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT operations for the tables involved. These triggers should be almost the same for every table, changing just the name and the association with its table.

For this suggestion, these tables should have audit columns, like one for the datetime when they rows were inserted and one for datetime when they rows were updated - at least. You can search for more audit ideas if you want (and need), like a column to know wich user triggered the insert/update, or how many times the row was altered, an so on.

You should elaborate a different approach to achieve this depending of how much data you intend to generate with these triggers.

I'm assuming you know how to do this with best practices (for example, you can [and should, IMHO] create these triggers dinamically to facilitate maintenance).

Finally, you will be able to elaborate a query from sys tables that contains information about tables and rows and return only the rows involved, ordered by these new columns (just an idea that I hope fits in your particular case).